# How do I extract a series of numbers from a list in the fashion below?

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I want to be able to extract certain numbers and exclude certain others, e.g.:
I am looking for an indexing syntax that can let me do `A[2:5` and then `7:]`.

This is the answer I expect from the procedure I want to try:

```
Anew = [3, 4, 5, 8, 9]
```

Also, will the operation be the same for arrays?

Comment: Welcome ! What is the logic you are expecting?

Comment: @GodIsOne They expect to concatenate the slices `A[2:5]` and `A[7:]`.

Comment: `A[2:5] + A[7:]` ?